# How to unmount and mount pen drive in ubuntu via command line

Tags: command-line

How to unmount and mount pen drive in Ubuntu 14.04?

Thanks

Comment: **To mount:**  https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount **To unmount:** https://linux.die.net/man/8/umount

Answer (score 48, accepted):

A. Identify the pendrive with the following commands

```
sudo parted -ls
sudo lsblk -fm
```

best in a wide terminal window (to avoid line wrapping)

```
df -h
```

to check if it is already mounted

B. Create mount points with mkdir and mount with the mount command

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/sdn
```

Make the mount point only the first time; n can be a number 1 or 2 ...

```
sudo mount /dev/sdxm /mnt/sdn
```

x is the drive letter, m is the partition number

for example

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/sd1
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sd1
```

C. Unmount with umount

```
sudo umount /mnt/sdn
```

where n can be a number 1 or 2 ...

or

```
sudo umount /dev/sdxm
```

where x is the drive letter and m is the partition number identified according to the command lines in A. (parted, lsblk, df).