# Insuficient permissions to mount USB

Tags: usb, permissions, mount

So I recently upgraded from 10.21 to 04.22.
It's been a while but I plugged in a good, working USB memory stick to copy files out.
I can see it in Files, but I'm now unable to access the contents of the USB as it comes up with a message advising that Mount must be done by Superuser.
User (which is the only profile on the laptop) is a superuser.
Any thoughts?
(I'm not a command-line whiz.)

Comment: Can you please confirm you recently upgraded from Ubuntu 21.10 to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: I think the following links to other threads at AskUbuntu can help you: [How to unmount and mount pen drive in ubuntu via command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859787/how-to-unmount-and-mount-pen-drive-in-ubuntu-via-command-line/859798#859798) and [Q:"How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?" --> A: "Set access via mounting"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072). Please notice that the same method works for all Microsoft file systems when used from Linux: NTFS and exFAT and the old FAT32.

Comment: Thanks for that.. 
None of the kb items worked, however I plugged the USB into a Win10 PC and checked it (it was accessible, but had attributes from a different usb).
I ejected it like a good boy (and took my time about extracting it) and found all was accessible and readable when I went back to my Ubuntu machine. No signs of previous message.