# WD Elements USB drive is not recognized

Tags: 20.04, mount, external-hdd

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
External drive: WD Elements 2Tb Portable (WDBMTM0020BBK-EEUE)

When I plug in the drive, dmesg reports that:

```
[10373639.389152] usb 2-3: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[10373639.410231] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=25a2, 
bcdDevice=10.26
[10373639.410234] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[10373639.410236] usb 2-3: Product: Elements 25A2
[10373639.410237] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[10373639.410238] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 575838314538xxxxxxxxx
```

but no new drives (/dev/sdX) appear in system. lsusb also "sees" the device:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1058:25a2 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements 25A2
```

The disk has a single encrypted ext4 partition. I tried USB 2.0/3.0, I am sure the drive has enough power to work, but it isn't recognized by the system.

I would appreciate any piece of advice on whether it's possible to "unhide" it somehow. Thanks.

**Update**: the command

```
lsblk -f
```

does not list the device.

Comment: It'd be clearer if you were specific as to what commands you used; ie. did you use `lsblk` to list block devices?  (`lsusb` concentrates on the electronics of plugged in devices & not the actual disk attached to those electronics), or did you try exploring using `fdisk` etc...

Comment: [This link 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072) and [this link 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859787/how-to-unmount-and-mount-pen-drive-in-ubuntu-via-command-line/859798#859798) and [this link 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1431937/adding-new-sata-ssd-hard-drive-not-showing-up-in-file-manager/1431961#1431961) may help you find your drive. As suggested by guiverc, `lsblk` with or without the option 'f', `lsblk -f` may help you find your portable drive.

Comment: @guiverc Affirmative, I used "lsblk -f", it doesn't list the device.

Comment: do you have `cryptsetup` installed?